# Parsing Data from For Loop - Batch CMD

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I am attempting to write a batch file that creates directories and moves image files based on the file name (Which happens to be the date taken). I am having issues with variables not setting properly. I run the code as it is shown below and no files are moved.

```
@echo Off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM Collect list of file names in current directory that have the .bmp file extension. Output to text file.
dir /b "*.bmp" >BMP.txt
REM For loop examines the text file for individual file names.
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%# in (C:\Users\jhavekos\Documents\Pinger\BMP.txt) do ( 
    REM SET variable "#" to equal "token"
    Set "token=%%#&&"
    REM Extract the first 4 characters (year) from the file name and set is to variable "tokenyear"
    Set "tokenyear=%%token:~0,4%%"
    REM Extract the month characters from the file name and set the variable as "tokenmonth"
    Set "tokenmonth=%%Token:~4,2%%"
    REM Copy from current directory to: Current Directory\ImageTakenYear\ImageTakenMonth\ 
    REM Any bmps with token year and token month get copied.
    Robocopy .\ ".\%%TokenYEAR\%%TokenMonth" %%TokenYEAR%%TokenMonth*.bmp
    REM Echo the variable tokenyear
    Echo %%tokenyear
    REM Echo the variable tokenmonth
    Echo %%tokenmonth
)
pause
```

The very last line of output is listed below:

```
%tokenmonth
%tokenyear
```

The RoboCopy Outputs as follows:
As you can see I need the variable to populate.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Fri Sep 09 14:41:38 2016

   Source : C:\Users\jhavekos\Documents\Pinger\
     Dest : C:\Users\jhavekos\Documents\Pinger\%TokenYEAR\%TokenMonth%\

    Files : %TokenYEAR%TokenMonth*.bmp

  Options : /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30
```

What do I need to change to get my variables to populate successfully?
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: While you have delayed expansion enabled you are not using it correctly.  This problem gets addresses a half dozen times a week on StackOverflow.  `Set "tokenyear=!token:~0,4!"`

Comment: @Squashman You are are correct. That (and some capitalization issues) fixed the problem. Thank you for your prompt help. Do understand correctly that you must use ! instead of %% in FOR loops operations? Also, I apologize for not finding those other questions. I guess I was not searching in the right places. I do hate to be "that" guy though!

Comment: Double percents are only used for the FOR variable. Environmental variables are surrounded by percents: `%var%`. When you are inside a code block, like your FOR command and you are manipulating variables then you need to use delayed expansion in which case you use `!var!`.

Answer (score 0):

`%%tokenyear` is not correct and does not expand to the variable value. You want %tokenyear%. Same with %tokenmonth%. Environment variables are not quite the same as batch arguments or for variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final product I ended up with. It has been edited thanks to help from @Squashman. I also added logic to change the month directory to the month name.

Thanks again!

```
@echo Off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM Collect list of file names in current directory that have the .bmp file extension. Output to text file.
dir /b "*.bmp" >BMP.txt
REM For loop examines the text file for individual file names.
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%# in (C:\Users\jhavekos\Documents\Pinger\BMP.txt) do ( 
    REM SET variable "#" to equal "token"
    Set "token=%%#"
    REM Extract the first 4 characters (year) from the file name and set is to variable "tokenyear"
    Set "tokenyear=!token:~0,4!"
    REM Extract the month characters from the file name and set the variable as "tokenmonth"
    Set "tokenmonth=!token:~4,2!"
    IF !tokenmonth!==01 (Set "tokenmonthdirectory=!tokenmonth! January")
    IF !tokenmonth!==02 (Set "tokenmonthdirectory=!tokenmonth! February")
    IF !tokenmonth!==03 (Set "tokenmonthdirectory=!tokenmonth! March")
    IF !tokenmonth!==04 (Set "tokenmonthdirectory=!tokenmonth! April")
    IF !tokenmonth!==05 (Set "tokenmonthdirectory=!tokenmonth! May")
    IF !tokenmonth!==06 (Set "tokenmonthdirectory=!tokenmonth! June")
    IF !tokenmonth!==07 (Set "tokenmonthdirectory=!tokenmonth! July")
    IF !tokenmonth!==08 (Set "tokenmonthdirectory=!tokenmonth! August")
    IF !tokenmonth!==09 (Set "tokenmonthdirectory=!tokenmonth! September")
    IF !tokenmonth!==10 (Set "tokenmonthdirectory=!tokenmonth! October")
    IF !tokenmonth!==11 (Set "tokenmonthdirectory=!tokenmonth! November")
    IF !tokenmonth!==12 (Set "tokenmonthdirectory=!tokenmonth! December")
    REM Copy from current directory to: Current Directory\ImageTakenYear\ImageTakenMonth\ 
    REM Any bmps with token year and token month get copied.
    Robocopy .\ ".\!tokenyear!\!tokenmonthdirectory!" !tokenyear!!tokenmonth!*.bmp
    REM Echo the variable tokenyear
    Echo !tokenyear!
    REM Echo the variable tokenmonth
    Echo !tokenmonth!
    Echo !tokenmonthdirectory!
)
pause
```